# XML Schema Validation Pattern Restriction Error

Tags: xml, validation, design-patterns, xsd, restriction

I have the following files:

`a.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<e xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="a.xsd">
  2
</e>
```

`a.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="e">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and when validating i get:

**Error:(4, 5) cvc-pattern-valid: Value '
2
' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[0-9]' for type '#AnonType_e'.**

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either change the pattern to allow the surrounding whitespace, or you could add a whitespace facet (="collapse") to force the whitespace to be ignored before the pattern is applied.